# Display a popup on long click in extended EditText class

Tags: android, android-edittext, popupwindow

I try to write a derived class of `EditText` for use on with dates

```
public class myEditDate extends EditText {
    protected Context mContext; // Current activity
    ...
```

It work fine and i add some utils date functions but i try to display a popup windows with a `CalendarView` widget.
on `LongClickListener` event i call

```
private void ShowCalendar()
{
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    mv_CALENDAR = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.editdate_calendar, null);

    final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(mv_CALENDAR, 400, 400);
}
```

I have an error :

```
   editdate_calendar cannot be resolved or is not a field
```

I think it's because i am into a field class and not into an activity class
How i can solve it

editdate_calendar.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/layout"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
 <CalendarView
    android:id="@+id/calendarView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:showWeekNumber="false" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it :

Replace 
    import android.R;
by
    import myPackage.R;

Sorry, I use CTRL + Shift + o to add missing imports and not see it